# configuration node.js windows 2008 server

Tags: windows, node.js, configuration

I did install all needed package and node.js to dedicated machine Windows 2008 Server.

```
 var http = require('http');
 var port = 1337;
 http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Hello World\n');
 }).listen(port, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port );
```

So when I call 
      http://local.host:1337/, 
I get 'Hello World'
But if try to call this service from another machine: 
http://my.domain.ip.address:1337/ Ooops, I can't see nothing.
I already switch Off firewall at all

Thanks, to All advices

Comment: You'd usually deploy node behind another server, the easiest to get this done if performance is not a huge issue is to put it behind IIS, if you get WebMatrix it comes with build in configuration files for that (I just don't know where else they're available online) if you create a Node project.

Answer (score 2):

Listening to [`localhost`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) or `127.0.0.1` only allows for responding to requests made from the same computer to that specific IP or hostname.

To have your application respond to requests for multiple IP addresses, you'll need to listen to each of them. You can either do this individually.

```
function server(req, res) {
    // ...
}

http.createServer(server).listen(port, '127.0.0.1');
http.createServer(server).listen(port, 'my.domain.ip.address');
http.createServer(server).listen(port, '<any other public facing IP address>');
```

Or, you can [listen to `IPADDR_ANY`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) ([`0.0.0.0`](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1)), which in a non-specific, meta address. And, this is the default value for the `hostname` argument, so you only need to specify the `port`.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // ...
}).listen(port);
```